# Two divs side by side, right div fixed width, left div taking up the remaining space

Tags: css, html

*** Thanks everyone for checking on this.  It appears I had a separate template file for the index page and I forgot to edit it.  I feel dumb having worked on this for 2 hours!.  Sorry for wasting your time.***

I am trying to get the `div id="right-sidebar"` to align to the right of the page, while the `div id="right-main"` to fill the remaining space to the left.  The `div id="right-main"` is aligning just fine and filling the space, but the right-sidebar is nowhere to be found.  Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong here to get the right sidebar to show up to the right of `div id="right-main"`?

**Here is my html:**

```
<div id="page-wrap"align="center">
  <div class="main" align="center">
    <div id="header" align="left"></div>
    <div id="subheader" align="bottom"></div>
    <div id="right-sidebar"></div>
    <div id="right-main"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**Here is my CSS:**

```
#page-wrap {
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
}

.main {
    /*min-width: 780px;*/
    max-width: 1260px;
    position: relative;
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border:1px solid #777777;

    /* Gradient background */
    background:#FFF;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5e99d4, #c4d7ea);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 75%, from(#5e99d4), to(#c4d7ea));

    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}


#header {
    padding:10px 20px 10px 10px;
    width: 90%;
    }

#sitepic {
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left; 
}
#p

#subheader {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    }

#wrapper {

}

#right-sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 300px;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border:1px solid #777777;
    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#right-main {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin-right: 210px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border:1px solid #777777;
    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }

#footer {
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    min-height: 40px;
    background: #5e99d4;
    position: relative;
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border:1px solid #777777;
    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }
```

Comment: right-sidebar appears to work correctly for me from jsFiddle using Chrome and IE8. What browser are you viewing this in?

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time guys... I forgot I had a separate template file for my index page and I didn't edit it when I added the sidebar.  I feel pretty dumb.  Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right-sidebar appears to work correctly for me from jsFiddle using Chrome and IE8. What browser are you viewing this in?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me as well. What makes you think you can't see it? Try putting your border to 10px and see if the right hand side gets thicker.

Comment: Still can't see it in chrome or firefox.  Here is the webpage.  http://fbcdesoto.com/attendance/admin/index.php

Comment: I commented above.  There was never a problem to begin with.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anything wrong. The "right-sidebar" div is sitting just beside the "right-main" div.
What browser are you using? It looks fine on Firefox.

Comment: I commented above.  There was never a problem to begin with.  Thanks.